# getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY') fails under certain conditions

Tags: php, html

I am calling `getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')` from `contact.php` file which is called from `contact.html` that describes the details of a standard contact form.

Everything goes fine but the **command**:

```
$sendgrid_apikey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
```

fails causing the **error**:

> {"errors":["Permission denied, wrong credentials"],"message":"error"}

The error shows after submitting the contact form with all required fields filled.

I can get it to work from a simple .php script such as:

```
<?php
     $sendgrid_apikey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
     echo "apikey: $sendgrid_apikey  \r\n"
?>
```

The above script echo's the `SENDGRID_API_KEY`, no problem at all. The issue happens when I call it in a `contact.php` that in turn is called from `contact.html` with the following form definition:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
```

Here is how SENDGRID_API_KEY is defined:

```
export SENDGRID_API_KEY = "abcdefgh"
source ~/.bashrc
```

If I invoke:

```
echo $SENDGRID_API_KEY
```

In the terminal, I get:

```
abcdefgh
```

Any idea where is this coming from?

Thanks

Comment: Where and how is `SENDGRID_API_KEY` defined?

Comment: SENDGRID_API_KEY is defined in .bashrc.

Comment: Whose `.bashrc`?  Apache will not have access to that?

Comment: I am running a static website using nginx.

Comment: The point is your webserver does not read your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks for information. I am examining some posts related to accessibility of environment variables by php and webservers.